# entity code first many-to-many relations saving

Tags: ef-code-first, many-to-many, save

I have spent a day with this problem. There are these entitites:

```
public class UserRole
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Privilege> Privileges { get; set; }
}

public class Privilege
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

And this configuration in context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>().HasMany<Privilege>(a => a.Privileges).WithMany(a => a.Roles)
.Map(m =>
    {
        m.MapLeftKey("RoleId");
        m.MapRightKey("PrivilegeId");
        m.ToTable("RolesPrivilegesMapping");
    });
```

And this test code:

```
UserRole role;
//get role entity from context
//write privileges count
using (VaultContext context = new VaultContext(connectionString))
{
    role = context.UserRoles.Where(a => a.Name == "Users").FirstOrDefault();
    Console.WriteLine(role.Privileges.Count.ToString()); //writes 0
}

//make offline changes
//the privilege already exists in database
role.Privileges.Add(new Privilege() { Id = 1, Name = "Login" });

//save changes to database
using (VaultContext context = new VaultContext(connectionString))
{
    List<Privilege> privileges = new List<Privilege>();
    foreach (Privilege p in role.Privileges)
    { privileges.Add(p); }
    foreach (Privilege p in privileges)
    { context.Privileges.Attach(p); }
    role.Privileges.Clear();
    context.UserRoles.Attach(role);
    context.Entry(role).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
    foreach (Privilege p in privileges)
    { role.Privileges.Add(context.Privileges.Find(p.Id)); }
    context.SaveChanges();
}

//reload the role entity
//write privileges count
using (VaultContext context = new VaultContext(connectionString))
{
    Console.WriteLine(context.UserRoles.Where(a => a.Name == "Users").FirstOrDefault().Privileges.Count.ToString()); //writes 0
}
```

The Users role and Login privilege is already in database. So I try to add privilege Login to Users role.
But relations are not saved in database - the RolesPrivilegesMapping table doesn't contain record with id corresponding with Users role and Login privilege.
If I simply add directly - it works, but it is not my target:

```
new UserRole() 
{ 
    Name = "Administrators", 
    Privileges = new List<Privilege>() 
    { 
        new Privilege() { Name = "Login" }
    }
}
```

Could anyone advice me how to add only many-to-many relations if all entities exist in database?
I'm using EF 5.0. I have tried it with EF 4.3 with same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your wanting to do is attach existing entries in your database, could you do somethign a bit simpler?

```
  using( VaultContext context = new VaultContext( ) )
         {
            role = context.UserRoles.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == "Users");
            Privilege p = context.Privileges.FirstOrDefault(pr => pr.Name == "Login");
            role.Privileges.Add(p);
            context.SaveChanges();
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.
This is my solution: (role is changed offline)

```
UserRole dbRole = context.UserRoles.Find(role.Id);
dbRole.Privileges.Clear();
foreach (Privilege p in role.Privileges)
{
    dbRole.Privileges.Add(context.Privileges.Find(p.Id));
}
context.Entry(dbRole).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
```